# Install google-api-php-client using the v1 branch

Tags: php, google-api, composer-php, google-api-client

I need to use Google APIs Client Library for PHP. I found on githuib the repository

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/tree/master

According whit the repository documentation if you want to install it via composer you'll need to run this command.

```
composer require google/apiclient:"^2.7"
```

They also clarify that **if you are using PHP 5.2 or 5.3**, it will be necessary to useuse **the v1 branch**.

Because **my server in production uses php 5.3** I need this option, but I don't know what would be the eqivalent composer command to download that branch.

Could you help me?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Time to upgrade your production server. That version of PHP doesn't receive fixes or security updates any more, and hasn't for several years. not a suitable platform to run a production application on.

Comment: I would like that.  But it doesn't depend only on me. What depends on me at this time is to find the solution to the problem of the question.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: It's not clear if there's a composer command you can use for it or not but it looks like the code is here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/tree/v1-master , you could always download it yourself

Answer (score 1):

`composer require google/apiclient:"^2.7"` requires any tagged version from the v2 branch, at least v2.7.

`composer require google/apiclient:"^1.0"` requires any tagged version from the v1 branch